# How to use StreamBuilder to print images from Firebase Storage inside a pdf

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flutter-widget

I'm trying to print images from a Firebase Storage inside a pdf, using the widgets library.
So I have a code like this

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;


          pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
              pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
              build: (pw.Context context) {
                return pw.Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <pw.Widget>[
                    pw.Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <pw.Widget>[
                        pw.Text(
                          dettagliUtente[0],
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13, fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          dettagliUtente[1],
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.blueGrey),
                        pw.Padding(
                          padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          "Referto: ",
                          style:
                              pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          _miosnap['referto'],
                          style: pw.TextStyle(),
                        ),
                            pw.Container(
                              height: 1000.0,
                              child: pw.StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                  stream: Firestore.instance
                                      .collection('visite')
                                      .where(
                                        "paziente",
                                        isEqualTo: idPaziente,
                                      )
                                      .where("visita",
                                          isEqualTo: dataVisitadbFormat)
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>
                                          snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                                      return Text(
                                          'Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                        return Center(
                                            child:
                                                CircularProgressIndicator());
                                      default:
                                        return GridView.builder(
                                            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                                            gridDelegate:
                                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                                            ),
                                            itemCount: snapshot
                                                .data.documents.length,
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                              DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot
                                                  .data.documents[index];

                                              return Card(
                                                child:
                                                    ImageItem(ds['file']),
                                                elevation: 10.0,
                                                shape:
                                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                        side: BorderSide(
                                                            width: 2,
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .blueGrey)),
                                              );
                                            });
                                    }
                                  }),
                            )
```

But inside the last container I have an error with the StreamBuilder like undefined function.
I cannot use Streambuilder inside the pdf.
How can I do to do the same thing to print images inside a pdf loading from a Firestore query and Firebase Storage?
Many thanks